# Search within two tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to search within two tables which are connected via foreign key.

The problem is, that **I need to somehow "merge" two columns named "attribute"** from each tables and search within them with an array using IN() and for exact match count use HAVING().

Tables look something like this

```
First table
----------
id         INT primary key 
name       VARCHAR 
attribute  INT
etc..

Second table
----------
id               INT primary key 
attribute        INT 
fg_first_table   INT foreign key
```

For example I have an imploded array (1, 2, 4, 5).
The number 1 is stored in the first table and the rest 2, 4, 5 in the second one. How to get ID from the first table WHERE those number match attribute col within two tables?

Is it even possible? Thanks.

**UPDATE: Table data**
Select an ID from first table where ARRAY (1, 2, 4, 5) matches cols attribute from both tables.

```
First table
----------
id        name                attribute      
-----------------------------------------------------
1         Something           1

Second table
----------
id        attribute           fg_first_table
-----------------------------------------------------
1         2                   1
2         4                   1
3         5                   1
```

Comment: Can you add table data and also expected result?

Comment: Try to re-phrase your question. It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Tried to do so, hope it helps.

Comment: Is it always the 1st value within the search array that is located in the 1st table?

Comment: You are looking for a tables Union or for other? in this second case plase explain better your goal..

Comment: post **expected result**  please

Comment: Need to return ID from the first table WHERE attribute IN (1, 2, 4, 5) HAVING COUNT = '4'.

Comment: when you do any query with mysql the expected result is a **recordset** with some columns filled with some values. so post please your expected result as you already posted raw source data samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to figure it out on my own and here it is.

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(DISTINCT(u.attribute)) AS attribute_count
FROM (
  SELECT id, attribute FROM first_table
  UNION
  SELECT fg_first_table AS id, attribute FROM second_table
) AS u
WHERE 
u.attribute IN (1, 2, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING attribute_count = 4 
ORDER BY RAND();
```